# Python compiler says I'm adding an extra argument to int in an Enum

Tags: python, enums

I'm trying to create a custom enumerator that can replace an int, but has additional fields.

```
from enum import IntEnum

class MD_Fields(IntEnum):
    ACCOUNT = (0, "Account", True)
    M_DESCRIPT = (4, "Description", False)

    def __new__(cls, value: int, description: str, identifier: bool):
        obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        obj.description = description
        obj.identifier = identifier
        return obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(MD_Fields.M_DESCRIPT)
```

However, this code raises the following problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../JetBrains/PyCharmCE2022.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 3, in <module>
    class MD_Fields(IntEnum):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 223, in __new__
    enum_member._value_ = member_type(*args)
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I don't understand what's happening.
(I didn't find a meaningful definition of `int.__new__`)

Comment: Can you clarify on why you want it to replace an int but also have additional fields as those seem mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Natecat Code expecting an `int` will ignore the extra attributes. Code aware of `MD_Fields` can still make use of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close - it was only missing the `obj._value_ = value` assignment, [which `Enum` needs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-dunder-names):

```py
from enum import IntEnum

class MD_Fields(IntEnum):
    ACCOUNT = (0, "Account", True)
    M_DESCRIPT = (4, "Description", False)

    def __new__(cls, value: int, description: str, identifier: bool):
        obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.description = description
        obj.identifier = identifier
        return obj
```

After adding that, it works as intended:

```
>>> for member in MD_Fields:
...     member, int(member), member.description, member.identifier
...
(<MD_Fields.ACCOUNT: 0>, 0, 'Account', True)
(<MD_Fields.M_DESCRIPT: 4>, 4, 'Description', False)
```

If you were only extending `Enum` instead of `IntEnum` (which is just a shortcut for extending both `int` and `Enum`), you would use `obj = object.__new__(cls)` instead.

The reason that `_value_` needs to be set is because `EnumMeta.__new__` will use its default behavior for setting `_value_` when it wasn't already stored on the member.  The relevant portion from the source for `EnumMeta.__new__` (in 3.10), which should look familiar from the error that occurred before that attribute was assigned a value in `MD_Fields.__new__`:

```py
if not hasattr(enum_member, '_value_'):
    if member_type is object:
        enum_member._value_ = value
    else:
        enum_member._value_ = member_type(*args)
```

Normally, the `._value_` attribute would be populated using the value to the right of the `=` when the member was defined.  That value ends up being exposed through the `.value` attribute for each member.

In 3.11, the error was improved to include the hint that `_value_` needs to be set:

```
TypeError: _value_ not set in __new__, unable to create it
```

Comment: Thanks @dskrypa This is very convoluted!